# Smooth switching between different divs (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've found this nice code to switch between various divs using next/prev buttons but I can't find a way to make the transition more smooth, something like fade in/out between switching. I tried adding fadein(); and fadeout(); in various places but I must be doing something wrong because it didn't change nothning. How should I modify it?

http://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/36/

```
<div class="divs">
<div class="cls1">1</div>
<div class="cls2">2</div>
<div class="cls3">3</div>
<div class="cls4">4</div>
<div class="cls5">5</div>
<div class="cls6">6</div>
<div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>



$(document).ready(function(){
$(".divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `show()` with `fadeIn()` and `hide()` with `fadeOut()`. You'll also need to add callbacks to the `fadeOut()` call so that `fadeIn()` starts running after the fade out is completed. Here is a fork of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8yJt/.

Answer (score 4):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/42/)

```
$(function(){

  var $el = $(".divs > div"),
      N = $el.length,
      C = 0;                   // Current    

    $el.hide().eq( C ).show();

    $("#next, #prev").click(function(){
       $el.stop().fadeOut().eq( (this.id=='next'? ++C : --C) %N ).fadeIn();
    });

});
```

<sub>Make sure to **CSS** `position:absolute;` your slide elements so that they overlap.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You only replace show() with fadeIn(),also can add a time to the fadeIn().